# PowerBi - Show last week (Monday to sunday)

Tags: filter, powerbi, dax, slicers

I'm fairly new to powerbi.

I want to be able to use a slicer to show the last week not the last 7 days.

I know you can use de relative week, but that shows the dates from Sunday to Monday.

I've also red that it's not possible to change the slicer settings for this.

Is it possible to archiev this in another way?

This is my date table https://i.stack.imgur.com/9GTco.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You can add a column that calculates last weeks' weeknumber and compares it to the weeknumber of the date in your row. Find the weeknumber for the current datetime (NOW), subtract 1, wrap that in an IF and you get a boolean to slice with:

```
LastWeek = IF((WEEKNUM(NOW(),2) - 1) = YourTableName[Weeknum],true,false)
```

Works the same as the relative week slicer option, but with the week starting on Monday.